# Data is always 'undefined' when POSTing form data through body-parser in node.js express

Tags: node.js, forms, express, parsing, body-parser

I've stripped down the form to the following for clarity:

```
      <form method="post" action="/form" id="testform" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="testform" novalidate>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" >
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Generate XML</button>
      </form>
```

in my main js file I have the following:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
```

and I'm receiving the data (or not, as the case may be) here:

```
.post('/form', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.name)
    console.log(req.body)
  })
```

and all I'm getting is "welcome, undefined", and the log is showing empty - {}

This is driving me insaaaaaaaaane how do I inspect what's sent? Debugging this is madness!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the `name` attribute on the `<input>` element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name">
```

You've already set an `id` but that can only be used for CSS selectors (`#name`), links (visiting `#name` will select that input) and `<label>` elements (using `for="name"`).

Comment: AAAAAHHHH. It had to something as idiotic as this.  Thank you thank you I had gone blind. I'd set the name attributes on associated buttons used in the js, and mixed everything up in my head.

Comment: this is development at its finest ;p

Answer (score 1):

Elements are recognized by the name parameter on the server side. You need to add a name attribute in the input tag.

Answer (score 1):

Give the input element a `name` attribute as `"name"` and the code will work fine.